# double click kills session in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

When I do a double-click on any image in the site (Zend Framework), I'm losing the session. Looks like ZF renames the session on the first click, and the second click reaches an old name of the session.

But maybe you have some other ideas? The symptom is that every mouse double click on an images - kills session. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we would really need a bit more information. In general ZF would have no reason to care if an image was clicked on or not. I assume you're handling the click through some sort of javascript.

Comment: PHP is a server-side language and can't operate on the client side of things. There would be no way without some javascript or similar setup for a PHP backend to even know that a click has happened.

Comment: Are you regenerating the id? This can cause problems with race conditions, especially with AJAX

Comment: Yes, I'm regenerating the ID of session. How to solve this problem? Any link/suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with "[session race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)".